# Endpoint issue for posting to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a simple 1 page webapp which uses AJAX to GET/POST mostly, however, when I try to run the SQL on one of my endpoints, it throws an internal server error and I can't think why, I tested my SQL command in PHPMyAdmin and it worked, I tested to be sure my values are being captured, and they are, so I cannot see the issue, any help would be great, here is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add a new album</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p class="yeah">Add a new album</p>

    <form action="http://localhost:8000/musicOnline/assets/scripts/php/create/new/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Artist Name" name="artist" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Album Name" name="album" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Genre" name="genre" required>
        <input type="date" placeholder="Release Date" name="release" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Record Label" name="recordLabel" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter a star rating (1 - 5)" name="rating">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

My AJAX handler:

```
//forms that post, put, delete or get
$(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $this = $(this),
        $data = $this.serializeArray(),
        $method = $this.attr("method"),
        $endpointURL = $this.attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        type: $method,
        data: $data,
        url: $endpointURL,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#content-lockup").html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error: " + textStatus + ", error thrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

And the endpoints code (/assets/scripts/php/create/new/):

```
<?php

require "http://localhost:8000/musicOnline/assets/scripts/php/dbConn/index.php";

$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$album = $_POST['album'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$release = $_POST['release'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$recordLabel = $_POST['recordLabel'];

try {
    //prepare our statement
    $preparedQuery = $conn->prepare("insert into albums (artistName, albumName, genre, releaseDate, recordLabel, rating) values ('" . $artist . "', '" . $album . "', '" . $genre . "', '" . $release . "', '" . $recordLabel . "', '" . $rating . "')");

    //execute the statement
    if($preparedQuery->execute()) {
        echo "success";

        $conn = null;
    } else {
        echo "nope";

        $conn = null;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

And my db connection:

```
<?php

session_start();

//setup variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "dgc_music_online";

//instantiate our PDO connection to the DB
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);

?>
```

And a screenshot of the console.log that is output:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your endpoint code to follow this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
//prepare our statement
$preparedQuery = $conn->prepare("insert into albums (artistName, albumName, genre, releaseDate, recordLabel, rating) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//execute the statement
if($preparedQuery->execute(array($artist, $album, $genre, $release, $recordLabel, $rating))) {
```

Comment: Still not working, I added more info to the question, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe problem because of string require "http://localhost:8000/musicOnline/assets/scripts/php/dbConn/index.php";
Because you include file over http and from manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php it means that:

This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.

Please rewrite require to get file not over http, but just from your file system

Answer (score 0):

In case of errors like that you should always the error details in you nginx/apache error logs. Most of the time there is something helpful recorded.

Comment: The logs say that they cannot find the file(I think it is referring to the db connection file, which you can see above), which I do not understand when I am using an absolute link, see my folder structure here as proof that it exists: [folder structure](https://puu.sh/nrxFB/0449bb3248.png), So my 2 questions are **1:** why is it throwing this error? and **2:** is my db connection stuff looking alright from what you see?